# Android - Get list of users and profile name

Tags: android, user-profile, profile-owner

We can create several users and profiles on an Android devices, for example, there is a Main User, and I also set a Work Profile with name "Work Profile".

Using the following adb command:

```
adb shell pm list users
```

I'm getting this result:

> UserInfo{0:My User:13} running
>       UserInfo{10:Work Profile:30} running

Good, I can see my User Info with the name Work Profile on it.
Now, I want to get this list from my application.

I tried to use this code:

```
for(Account account: AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts()) {
        DebugLog.e("COUCOU " + account.name + " " + account.toString());
    }
```

But the Work Profile account is not appearing in the list. Only the main user...
Any idea how I could get the same list as the ADB shell command??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing users with accounts. What you are using will only get you the accounts of the current user.

A device can have multiple users, which are the equivalent of users on a computer.

A user can have multiple accounts, i.e., let that be Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, etc. The accounts may be shared among users or not.

For more info on that topic, check out [the official page on Supporting Multiple Users](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user.html).

You can handle users with [UserManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html) and you can get the list of the profiles of the current user using [getUserProfiles](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html#getUserProfiles()), but what you'll get is a [UserHandle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserHandle.html) (which you can use to get the userId), how to get the list of all users and the name is something I haven't found out yet, but on the worst case you can use the shell command pm, as shown in this [post about Multiple user accounts on Android](http://zielenkiewicz.info/2012/10/01/Multiple_user_accounts_inside_Android_4_1/).

Answer (score 4):

If you have the root access to your device, or you are able to build your app as a system privileged application, you can use [Privileged Permission Whitelisting](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-whitelist) to obtain the `android.permission.MANAGE_USERS` permission (which also requires you to [sign your app with the platform signature](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/sign_builds)). Then, you can get a list of all [UserInfo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0e2d281/core/java/android/content/pm/UserInfo.java)s by calling [`UserManager.getUsers()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/56a2301/core/java/android/os/UserManager.java#261) using Java reflection.