# Can't find getUsers() method in class UserManager

Tags: android

How do I list all users on an Android device?

I have tried 2 approaches:

## 1. `UserManager.getUsers()`

In the [android source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/UserManager.java), there seems to be a `getUsers()` method in the `UserManager` class that does exactly what I need. However, the [android reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html) does not mention the method, and Android Studio can't resolve the method either.

Furthermore, the source shows that `getUsers()` returns `UserInfo` type (`import android.content.pm.UserInfo;`), but it is also not in the documentation or in Android Studio.

## 2. `UserManager.getUserProfiles()`

This method is documented in the [android reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html#getUserProfiles()).

Create some dummy users:

```
adb shell pm create-user dummy1
adb shell pm create-user dummy2
```

Calling `getUserCount()` confirms there are now 3 users. However, `getUserProfiles()` still only returns 1 item in the list!

It's probably because a Profile is different to a User. So I tried a few variations of create-user and the following looks promising:

```
adb shell pm remove-user dummy1
adb shell pm remove-user dummy2
adb shell pm create-user --profileOf 0 --managed profile1
adb shell pm create-user --profileOf 0 --managed profile2
```

Note that `profile2` couldn't be created (`Error: couldn't create user.`)

This time, calling `getUserCount()` confirms there are now 2 users. Also, `getUserProfiles()` confirms there are 2 items in the list. Unfortunately it seems that only one user of this type can be created, which is not useful for me as I need several additional users.

So this still doesn't answer my original question.

## Solution: Reflection

`getUsers()` is hidden, so use reflection to access it:

```
Method method = um.getClass().getMethod("getUsers", null);
Object users = method.invoke(um, null);
```

Warning: since it's hidden, there are no guarantees the API won't change in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is hidden with `@hide`. The method also requires the system permission `android.Manifest.permission.MANAGE_USERS`. This permission cannot be granted to third-party apps.

**UserManager#getUsers() documentation:**

> Returns information for all users on this device, including ones
>   marked for deletion. To retrieve only users that are alive, use
>   getUsers(boolean).
>
> Requires android.Manifest.permission.MANAGE_USERS permission.
>
> Returns:
>       the list of users that exist on the device.

---

> How do I list all users on an Android device?

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42394588/1048340) answer, you could possibly use [`getUserProfiles`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html#getUserProfiles()).

Comment: `android.Manifest.permission.MANAGE_USERS` can be granted to third-party apps that have the platform key. This can be easily granted for apps running on Android emulator images since they are built with the [default platform key](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/target/product/security).

Comment: I think your answer might help me solve the problem because you pointed me towards the `@hide` decorator. I used reflection to call the hidden method and it seems to return all users on the device. See OP for solution.